# Line between table rows

Tags: html

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PageTitle!</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<table id="Table_01" width="590" height="531" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>    <td>
            <a href="http://mypage.com" border="0"><img src="top.jpg" width="590" height="90" alt="" border="0"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://mypage.com" border="0"><img src="content.jpg" width="590" height="441" alt="" border="0"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And here what's the problem:

*Sorry, i have to remove this picture*

Why there is a line break between `<tr>` in table? I'm looking for not CSS solution, this is a simple mailing. And the problem with it shows **only in gmail**. When I download in to sparrow or mobile device empty row is disappear.

Comment: Note to self: get eyes checked.

Comment: http://www.csarven.ca/tr-border-trick-for-ie

Comment: You should really stop using inline CSS. Have you tried `border-collapse: collapse;` in the table? *EDIT* Now that I see what you are trying to do: Don't use tables for layout stuff.

Comment: I have to - this is a simple mailing, so there is HAVE TO be plain HTML without CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the CSS on the images to:

```
img {vertical-align:middle;}​
```

You could also float them left but that seems unnecessary.

See this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WRBwq/)**. Then remove the CSS and the gap re-appears.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define a doctype http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: This problem happened to me and took me ages to work out the problem. I had to try a few different doctype until it worked.